# How to fix missing pipewire screen capture option or the black screen in OBS?

Tags: arch-linux, obs-studio

## Problem

- After installing `obs-studio` from official Arch repos, it doesn't provide `Screen Capture (Pipewire)` option with Wayland or just captures black screen with cursor, although `v27+` OBS has native support for Wayland Screen Recording.
- Passing `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` makes OBS crash, or just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

- Make sure you read up on Pipewire Usage in [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Usage).
- Accordingly, you should have `xdg-desktop-portal` and its right backend installed according to the DE/WM in use.
- And make sure `qt5-wayland` package is installed as well, since OBS is a Qt5 application.

The last one did it for me and it had nothing to do with `pipewire` ;)

Comment: Ina addition to the i had to set `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=sway` to my environment, This [comment](https://old.reddit.com/r/voidlinux/comments/p0kx8e/obs_not_capturing_screen_on_kde_wayland_pipewire/hehgeu9/) really helped

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Wayland on PopOS 22.04 running the Flatpak version of OBS. No Pipewire screen capture option. (Maybe happens on Ubuntu 22.04 too?) `xdg-desktop-portal` was installed, but not `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome`. Installing that, then logging back in fixed it for me. \o/